# Granular Storage Account Cost Monitoring Per Container

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I would like to learn if it's possible to monitor Azure Storage account costs at container / folder level. The documentation doesn't state anything about this, but maybe there's someone who made some kind of automated workaround. :)

We're currently setting up infrastructure provisioning automation using Terraform. We have multiple compute resources sharing the same storage account. The compute resources have tags so the individual costs can be seen from the cost monitoring.

The storage of the workloads, however, is shared in a single storage account... but different container and folders. Is it possible to put tags for cost tracking there?

Comment: AFAIK, Container level cost analysis is not available in azure. Using cost analysis resource in Azure portal, you can view cost used for different services like Files, Tables, Queues and Blobs in Azure.

 In Azure portal, navigate to **Cost Management** resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Container level cost analysis is not available in azure.

Using cost analysis resource in Azure portal, you can view cost used for different services like Files, Tables, Queues and Blobs in Azure.

- In Azure portal, navigate to **Cost Management** resource.
- Click on cost analysis and select resource as storage account.
  [image]
- As seen in above image, cost analysis for storage account can be viewed for each service.

reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/cost-analysis-common-uses)